# Как лучше организовать БД

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, архитектура

У меня есть три таблицы, у которых есть поле даты. Это поле является фореин ключем который ссылается на ентити из таблицы date. Таким образом от этих entities получается связь many to one к моей дате.
Экземпляр даты мое приложение создает самостоятельно если такой даты еще нет в бд, извлекая id новосозданной даты, чтобы затем использовать ее в качестве референс ключа. Или берет id старой даты, если находит уже существующую.

Как это организовать красивее? А так же сделать автоудаление даты, если на нее больше не ссылаются никакие ентити

Comment: Вообще это очень странно - делать справочник дат. Вам точно нужен такой справочник дат?

Comment: вот за этим и пришел.. Думаете лучше будет просто сделать поле даты?

Comment: Я думаю да, лучше использовать поле дата. Кроме того, обычно стараются ничего из базы не удалять, а просто помечают записи удалёнными. Если только у вас реально с местом проблема прям в край, тогда да. А так обычно всё хранят - мало ли что нужно будет выяснить потом насчёт того, что было когда-то.